# Is this jQuery ajax call vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: php, javascript, xss, ajax

If somebody can edit `$("#field").val()`, can they change the url property here to point to another location?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mywebsite/script?param=" + $("#field").val(),
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(response) {
      document.write(/*fields from response object*/);
  },
 });
```

If they can then my page is XSS vulnerable since the malicious location could return script tags in the response object. I want to know if any value of `field` could be used to change the AJAX url.

**Update**

**My apologies, I have updated the question. The value is actually contained in a javascript variable and is not directly written by php (otherwise there is obviously XSS issues). Sorry.**

Comment: I think we would need to see the code of your server side `script`. Also, those files referenced by `fname`, are they HTML files, or plain text?

Comment: fname is just any parameter entered by the user eg from a `GET` request.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that based on what they enter into fname, results will come out. What do those results look like?

Comment: Wow thats an obvious xss flaw. Perhaps you should brush up on the basics before burdening others with such questions.

Comment: @Rook yep, see update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is vulnerable, but not it the way you suspect. The attacker would not try modify the loaded URL, but to execute the code directly. For example:

```
$_GET['fname'] = '"+(function(){/*any_code_i_like*/})()+"';
```

will become:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://mywebsite/script?param="+(function(){/*any_code_i_like*/})()+""
```

and the code will execute even before requesting the URL with ajax. It's just an example, *there are other vectors that would work here too*. The simplest way to escape the parameter to prevent XSS in this context would be using `urlencode()` in PHP like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://mywebsite/script?param=<?php echo urlencode($_GET["fname"]); ?>"
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(response) {
      document.write(/*fields from response object*/);
  },
 });
```

Also, take a look at [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

**Update:** After you updated the question - there is no XSS vulnerability here (you can't e.g. point the request to another domain), but the example is vulnerable to a different beast - [HTTP parameter polution](http://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2009/05/http-parameter-pollution-new-web-attack.html). It might not matter in this exact case, but imagine that the given parameter is:

```
a_valid_value&param=another_param_injected
```

The attacker is able to inject additional HTTP GET parameters which might be important for your application and might change the execution flow (e.g. parameter `admin=1`). You should get into habit of escaping/encoding everything coming from user input. In this modified case you should use Javascript `encodeURIComponent` function which prevents attacker from injecting '&','=' and '?':

```
"http://mywebsite/script?param=" + encodeURIComponent($("#field").val()),
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. I actually realised that the input is not directly added by php, see update.